# Do unrendered React components listen to Actions?

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I'm working on a React application and I've encountered a problem. I'm trying to pass data from an overview page (`/`) to another view, `ShowAllView` (`/#/showall`).

I made an `Action` which passes the data from overview. The `ShowAllView` class listens to that `Action`. However, it does not seem that it's triggered in the `ShowAllView` class. If I try to listen to the action in a component within the overview, it works perfectly fine.

The `ShowAllView` class did not perform its `render()` method at the time of the `Action`.

I'm using React with Reflux.

Does anyone know a solution to pass the data from one view to another? Or how an unrendered component should listen to `Action`s?

**EDIT**

overview.jsx:

```
//some method
Actions.selectTab(selectedTab);
```

showall.jsx

```
mixins:[
Reflux.listenTo(Actions.selectTab, "setSelectedTab")
]
//...some more code
```

Maybe this helps a bit:

```
var Routes = (
    <Route handler={App} path='/'>
        <DefaultRoute handler={OverView} />
        <Route name='showall' handler={ShowAllView}></Route>
    </Route>
);
```

Comment: We need more code to udnerstand what you really mean

Comment: Why aren't you listening for a change to your store in the other component rather than an action?

Answer (score 0):

For view state that needs to be known by different pages/components I use an App.Store. The app Store listens for actions, sets properties then triggers an event which is picked up by the listening upper level component which sets state which propagates through props to render in components. Its a circular thing which works to keep your logic clear.